# Adding behaviour using Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a bunch of projects which declare some spring bean files. I would like to write a "library" which supplies a utility which takes some bean names and adds some behaviour "around" the objects (example: Call Counting, Monitoring, Logging etc)

One obvious way for doing this would be to add some AspectJ annotations in the spring xml files in the projects but I would like the "utility" to search for some beans and add behaviour to them (This way the projects themselves are not aware of the utility).

The utility will be declared in the spring xml file somewhere so it has access to the ApplicationContext as it could implement ApplicationContextAware interface however I am keen on exploring how one would go about modifying behaviour of another bean in the app context programmatically. ex, something like find a bean of id "OrderService", create an aspected bean with some monitoring/call counting etc around all methods and replace that bean in the application context for "OrderService"

I know there are disadvantages with this approach but what I am after is "IS it possible to do this? And if yes how?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use AOP, you can achieve this using a [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html). The Spring documentation [states](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp):

> The BeanPostProcessor interface defines callback methods that you can
>   implement to provide your own (or override the container's default)
>   instantiation logic, dependency-resolution logic, and so forth. If you
>   want to implement some custom logic after the Spring container
>   finishes instantiating, configuring, and otherwise initializing a
>   bean, you can plug in one or more BeanPostProcessor implementations.

So you may create and register a BeanPostProcessor and implement the `postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)` method to modify the methods you want to customize. Here is an [example](http://www.springindepth.com/2.5.x/0.10/ch03s13.html#d0e3261).

(But I would still recommend that you do this with AOP as this is the classical use case for it and it's much easier and more declarative. With the [bean() pointcut](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/09/24/the-new-bean-pointcut/), you can even advise beans with names matching a certain pattern.)

Comment: I was nearly going to write my own BeanPostProcessor but the "BeanNameAutoProxyCreator" described in the blog you have mentioned is exactly what I am after !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html). You just have two declare it in `applicationContext.xml` and it will be called for each bean during initialization of beans (in fact, just before or just after). In each call you get a the actual object and its name. There, you can, for example, wrap that object depending on its name or type.